# assigning NSNumber object to NSString object won't cause any error or warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsobject

I've put NSNumber object into NSDictionary object, and then pop and assign it to a variable declared as NSString instance.

```
NSString *test;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1000] forKey:@"key"];

test = [dict valueForKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"%@, type of %@", test, NSStringFromClass([test class]));

return 0;
```

After running the above code, I've found that the type of test, declared as (NSString *) is __NSCFNumber. Why did it happen and why compiler did give no warning or errors?
Do I have to NSString constructor, such as NSStringWithFormat..., in order to keep test as NSString's instance?

Comment: Welcome to the world of dynamic typing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357063/what-is-the-class-nscfnumber-in-ios-4-1

Answer (score 5):

The reason this did not fail or warn you is because `valueForKey:` returns an object of type `id` which you can assign to any Objective-C type. You need to be aware of what type of value you are getting back from your collections to safely use them. In this case you know it contains an `NSNumber` so you should expect an `NSNumber` and if you need a string you will need to do the proper conversions.

```
NSNumber *test = [dict valueForKey:@"key"];
NSLog(@"%@, type of %@", test, NSStringFromClass([test class]));

//If you need a string
NSString *testStr = [test stringValue];
```